# $\{0,0,1,1,2,2,....n-1,n-1\} $ is a given set of $2n$ integers

Tags: combinatorics

$\{0,0,1,1,2,2,....n-1,n-1\} $ is a given set of $2n$ integers.We need to show that it is always possible to find $n$ integers among them such that A.M of these integers is always an integer and is least.Find the least value also.

I have simply no idea how to approach this problem. Thank you for helping.

Comment: What does A.M. stand for? Sorry

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour: Maybe Arithmetic Mean?

Comment: @some1.new4u Oh thanks, yes that makes sense.

Comment: This might be irrelevant but $\{0,0,1,1,2,2,...,n-1,n-1\}$ is not a set in the usual sense, it's a multiset. You're welcome @RustynYazdanpour.

Comment: Arithmetic Mean.

Comment: There is an *obvious* approach for starting the problem: try special cases. e.g. try to solve the $n=1$ by itself. Then the $n=2$ case. Then the $n=3$ case.

Answer (score 3):

A big hint: first, consider the condition for the arithmetic mean to be an integer.  You're looking at a sub(multi)set $S\subset\{0,0,1,1,\ldots,n-1,n-1\}$ of size $|S|=n$, so the arithmetic mean of $S$ will be $\dfrac{\sum_{s\in S}s}{n}$, and this will be an integer exactly if $\sum_{s\in S}s$ is a multiple of $n$.

Now, take the smallest possible $n$-element sub(multi)set $S$ of your given multiset.  How far below a multiple of $n$ can $\sum_{s\in S}s$ be?  What are the largest elements in $S$?  Can you see how we can bring the sum up to a multiple of $n$ by changing at most two elements of $S$?